# Generating tags programmatically with Bootstrap Tags Input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to use [tags input (from here)](http://formvalidation.io/examples/bootstrap-tagsinput/):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap.tagsinput/0.4.2/bootstrap-tagsinput.css" />
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap.tagsinput/0.4.2/bootstrap-tagsinput.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" name="modalites" class="form-control"
           value="" data-role="tagsinput" />
```

I work well. When I press enter (after typing), the tag appears. Now I'm trying to generate (in Javascript) those kind of input:

```
var cellModalite = row.insertCell(3);
cellModalite.innerHTML = "<input class='form-control' type='text' name='modalites[]' value='' data-role='tagsinput'>";
```

The field is created, but doesn't work properly: when I hit enter, the tag is not added (interpretted as form validation attempt). I don't know why it works perfectly when added manually, but does not work when generated.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Bootstrap Tags is looking for inputs with that data attribute on document ready (or some point when the page loads).  It will not be aware of them after the page is loaded.  After you add the HTML, you'll need to tell it to apply the tags as seen in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24104930/how-to-bind-bootstrap-tags-to-dynamically-created-elements

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I'll check that link later...

Comment: The given link did the job (with a little upgrade, but the general idea was here). You should consider adding an answer so I could accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap Tags is looking for inputs with that data attribute on document ready (or some point when the page loads). It will not be aware of them after the page is loaded. After you add the HTML, you'll need to tell it to apply the tags as seen in this question: [How to bind Bootstrap Tags to dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24104930/how-to-bind-bootstrap-tags-to-dynamically-created-elements)

To do it the "jQuery" way:

```
var tagInput = $('<input />', {
    class: 'form-control',
    type: 'text',
    name: 'modalites[]'
});
tagInput.appendTo($('#SomeElement'));
tagInput.tagsinput({
    // config for tags input
});
```